# using options_for_select in nested form rails @class.associative_class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

In my rails application, Im using a form for costs and a nested form for dependent_costs.

Costs has_many dependent_costs and dependent_costs belong_to costs.

This is where I am having issues:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id='dependency'>
        <section id="new-dependency">
            <div class="col-xs-3 center-block">
                <%= f.fields_for :cost_dependencies, @cost.cost_dependency do |dependency| %>
                <%= dependency.label :dependency_category, "Dependent Category" %>
                <%= dependency.select :dependency_category, options_for_select(getAllCategories, :selected => @cost.cost_dependency.dependency_category.nil? ? 'Please Select' : @cost.cost_dependency.dependency_category), {}, {:class => 'form-control', id: "category-select"} %>
            </div>
        </section>
</div>
```

It's at the `options_for_select` part. I receive a no method dependency_category for `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`
and i'm not quite sure where to move forward from here. because I would like to use this form for both new and edit methods as I have done in the past.

Misc files in case that is helpful: 
Model cost and cost_dependency:

```
class Cost < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cost_dependency
    validates :per_job, numericality: true
    validates :per_page, numericality: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cost_dependency
end
```

.

```
class CostDependency < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :cost 
    validates :per_job, numericality: true
    validates :per_page, numericality: true
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The reason of your error is that `@cost.cost_dependency` returns an array of associated objects (because of `has_many` relation), so you cannot just call `dependency_category` for array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@cost.cost_dependency
```

returns a collection, `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, not an not an instance of the `CostDependency` class, thus error.

May be you've meant to write the following?

```
@cost.cost_dependency.pluck(:dependency_category)
```

I assume, that `dependency_category` is an attribute of `CostDependency` model.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because you are right, but I also needed to take out the `@cost.cost_dependency` before the `do` as well.